# Calculator in Java: How to return to the main menu?

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement

I've writter a calculator program in Java, after a user is done with work,
I want this to happen:
i'll ask if he wants to do more operations, if yes, the program should return to choice input. If no, break the program.
What lines should I add to the code? This is my calc program:

```
import java.util.*;
class calc
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        char choice;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO SHREYDAN'S CALC 1.0");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("YOU CAN DO THE FOLLOWING:");
        System.out.println("+: ADDITION");
        System.out.println("-: SUBTRACTION");
        System.out.println("*: PRODUCT");
        System.out.println("/: QUOTIENT");
        System.out.println("#: SQUARE ROOT");
        System.out.println("^: POWER");
        System.out.println("$: ROUND OFF");
        System.out.println("!: FACTORIAL");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("ENTER CHOICE");
        choice=in.next().charAt(0);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case '+':
                System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                double a=in.nextDouble();
                double b=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("SUM = "+(a+b));
                break;
            case '-':
                System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                double c=in.nextDouble();
                double d=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("SUBTRACTING "+d+" FROM "+c+" ... DIFFERENCE = "+(c-d));
                break;
            case '*':
                System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                double e=in.nextDouble();
                double f=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("PRODUCT = "+(e*f));
                break;
            case '/':
                System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                double g=in.nextDouble();
                double h=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("DIVIDING "+g+" BY "+h+" = "+(g/h));
                break;
            case '#':
                System.out.println("ENTER NO. FOR SQAURE ROOT:");
                double sqrt=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("SQUARE ROOT OF "+sqrt+" = "+Math.sqrt(sqrt));
                break;
            case '^':
                System.out.println("ENTER BASE, USER");
                double base=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("ENTER POWER, USER");
                double power=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(base+" RAISED TO POWER "+power+" = "+Math.pow(base,power));
                break;
            case '$':
                System.out.println("ENTER DECIMAL VALUES TO ROUND OFF");
                double deci=in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("THE NEAREST ROUND OFF = "+Math.round(deci));
                break;
            case '!':
                System.out.println("ENTER A NO. FOR FACTORIAL:");
                int fact=in.nextInt();
                int factorial=1;
                for(int i=fact; i>=1;i--)
                    factorial=factorial*i;
                System.out.println(fact+"! = "+factorial);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("WRONG CHOICE USER");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import java.util.*;

class calc {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        char choice;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO SHREYDAN'S CALC 1.0");
        System.out.println(" ");

        boolean loop = true;
        while (loop) {
            System.out.println("YOU CAN DO THE FOLLOWING:");
            System.out.println("+: ADDITION");
            System.out.println("-: SUBTRACTION");
            System.out.println("*: PRODUCT");
            System.out.println("/: QUOTIENT");
            System.out.println("#: SQUARE ROOT");
            System.out.println("^: POWER");
            System.out.println("$: ROUND OFF");
            System.out.println("!: FACTORIAL");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("ENTER CHOICE");
            choice = in.next().charAt(0);
            switch (choice) {
                case '+':
                    System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                    double a = in.nextDouble();
                    double b = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("SUM = " + (a + b));
                    break;
                case '-':
                    System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                    double c = in.nextDouble();
                    double d = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("SUBTRACTING " + d + " FROM " + c + " ... DIFFERENCE = " + (c - d));
                    break;
                case '*':
                    System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                    double e = in.nextDouble();
                    double f = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("PRODUCT = " + (e * f));
                    break;
                case '/':
                    System.out.println("ENTER 2 NUMBERS, USER");
                    double g = in.nextDouble();
                    double h = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("DIVIDING " + g + " BY " + h + " = " + (g / h));
                    break;
                case '#':
                    System.out.println("ENTER NO. FOR SQAURE ROOT:");
                    double sqrt = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("SQUARE ROOT OF " + sqrt + " = " + Math.sqrt(sqrt));
                    break;
                case '^':
                    System.out.println("ENTER BASE, USER");
                    double base = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("ENTER POWER, USER");
                    double power = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(base + " RAISED TO POWER " + power + " = " + Math.pow(base, power));
                    break;
                case '$':
                    System.out.println("ENTER DECIMAL VALUES TO ROUND OFF");
                    double deci = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("THE NEAREST ROUND OFF = " + Math.round(deci));
                    break;
                case '!':
                    System.out.println("ENTER A NO. FOR FACTORIAL:");
                    int fact = in.nextInt();
                    int factorial = 1;
                    for (int i = fact; i >= 1; i--)
                        factorial = factorial * i;
                    System.out.println(fact + "! = " + factorial);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("WRONG CHOICE USER");
            }
            System.out.println("Want to calculate more?Y/N");
            loop = in.next().charAt(0) == 'Y';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the program logic in a loop. 
Try using a while loop

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    boolean doContinue = true;
    while(doContinue){
        char choice;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //program logic
        //when the user enters a command to end
        // set continue=false

    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that `continue` is a reserved keyword and this code doesn't compile. By the way, you don't even need this variable, you can just use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: Pseudo code doesn't really have reserved words. On that subject though, they're using switch statements, using the 'break' keyword to exit the loop will make things more confusing(to read).

Comment: You should either write pseudo code or Java code. If you are writing the former, don't use things such as `public static void main(String args[])` and generally make it clear that it is pseudo code. Good point about `break`, you could however use labels.

Comment: while(true) is harder to figure out what's going on. while(someCondition) gives me something to look through the code for. I can find all the places where someCondition changes, finding 'break' will be harder.

Answer (score 1):

while loops are your best bet for this type of problem, just think of a condition which the user can choose to toggle the boolean condition.

for example if the user chooses no on the "continuing of operations" choice, then toggle the boolean to false and exit the while loop to end the program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the entire program inside a while loop with a continue to run bool condition which could be set false when they want to quit